# check if string matches a pattern

Tags: python

So I am stuck with this problem
I need to solve this question:
given a word and a pattern, I need to write function that return true if the word matches the pattern.
The pattern looks like: "______"
for example: the word "apple" will be represented as "a _ _ l *" or "* _ _ _ *" or "* p p _ e", etc...
The conditions are:

1. The word needs to contain the exact characters revealed (=not "_") at the same index as in the pattern
2. the revealed characters in the pattern can't appear in other place in the word other than the same index

for example:
given the pattern "d _ _ _ _ a _ _ _ _"
for the word "delegating" return True
for the word "dishwasher" return True
for the word "derogation" return True

I wrote this code:

```
def check_exact_locations(word, pattern):
word_list = list(word)
pattern_list = list(pattern)
for i in range(len(word_list)):
    if word_list[i] in pattern:
        for j in range(1, len(pattern_list)):
            if pattern_list[j] != "_":
                if pattern_list[j] != pattern_list[j-1]:
                    if word_list[i] == pattern_list[j] and i != j:
                        return False
return True
```

I can't import any module so I pretty much need to use python's basics

Comment: Please clarify the question.  What is wrong / not working with the code you have written?  What is the *exact* question? Written above are a series of statements; I don’t see a single question.

Comment: You can convert the pattern to a regex pattern by doing `re_patern = pattern.replace('_', '.')` and then simply do `re.match(re_pattern, word)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this just by iterating over once and returning False when you find something that doesn't match:

```
def check_exact_loactions(word, pattern):
    if len(word) != len(pattern):
        return False
    for w, p in zip(word, pattern):
        if p != '_' and w != p:
            return False
    return True
```

(Edited with @Tomerikoo's suggestion)

Comment: The second loop can be `for w, p in zip(word, pattern)` and then replace `word[i]` and `pattern[i]` with `w` and `p` respectively

Comment: Use `all(p=="_" or w==p for w, p in zip(word, pattern))` instead of the for loop and if